# Kernel Panic Troubleshooting For Dummies

Tags: kernel, updates, troubleshooting

I have made Ubuntu my primary OS since 10.04, and I have converted many of my friends and neighbors into Ubuntu users since then. I am the fix-it guy they approach when they encounter problems. The most frantic calls I get are when they encounter an "update-induced kernel panic." (*Many human beings are allergic to command-line interfaces and search engines.*)

What are the step-by-step procedures to resolve an "update-induced kernel panic"?

Answer (score 4):

My ideas:

- Make sure you always **keep at least one older and stable kernel version  installed**.
  That way, if a new kernel update causes the panic, you will still be able to restart your system with the old one.
- **Write down as much information as you can regarding the error**.
  Take a photo of the screen output with your mobile phone perhaps.
  Post these messages here or in other related forums so that someone else can help you out.
- **Keep an Ubuntu Live-CD always close**.
  A package update might screw things up, but you'll still be able to boot and through a chroot make the necessary uninstallation/reinstallation of the package.

Comment: Thanks - +1  Can you add some links to how to apply chroot in this case, either to improve bug reports or to fix the installation?